# Program in $PATH not being found

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, environment-variables

I am running xubuntu 12.1, and am having some difficulty getting a program I have added to my path to execute.

The program I am attempting to execute is `scan-view`, from Clang. I built Clang from source, and as recommended, added [scan-build and scan-view to my PATH](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/installation.html).

`echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/paul/clang_build/Debug+Asserts/bin:/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build:/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view
```

Which is what I expect. `clang` and `scan-build` both work fine, but when I try `scan-view` from the shell, I get:

```
The program 'scan-view' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install clang
```

However, giving a complete path to scan-view opens it:

```
/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view/scan-view
```

I'm sure I'm making a silly mistake, but have tried everything I can think of.

**Update**: I am still having the same issue. Not sure if it's relevant, but I noticed `scan-build`, which is working, is  a ruby script, while `scan-view` is a python script. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after adding the path to $PATH?

Comment: @Jobin Yes, I have restarted several times since making the modification the path, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that the resulting binary/script is flagged as executeable?

`chmod 755 SOMEFILE` or `chmod +x SOMEFILE`

an example listing for validation sake:

```
ls -al $HOME/bin/juju-recycle-local

-rwxr-xr-x 1 charles charles 562 Jan 17 18:00 /home/charles/bin/juju-recycle-local
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be only adding the path to where the bins are located not the full path

try

`export PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/paul/clang_build/Debug+Asserts/bin:/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools"`

im not sure why `scan-build` works. can you post the output of `whereis scan-build`

Comment: The bin paths are actually `/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-view` and `/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build`. The executable run for `scan-build` is at `/home/paul/llvm/tools/clang/tools/scan-build/scan-build`.